# Having a navigation bar onclick/href execute animation on a circle element then loading a new page - How?

Tags: javascript, html, css, click, css-animations

I have a circle class element `.circle` and a navigation bar on a demo homepage `home.html`. I need clicking on one of the navigation's elements `href` to resume.html) to do an animation (growing its dimension) to have it matched in size to a similar element `.circleRe` on the linked page (resume.html) and *only then* move to that page. So, how to delay loading the second page while doing the animation?

P.S. The circle also response to hovering (and slightly enlarging it to have a text.)

I've tried using JavaScript and had partial success, but it seems that the `href` cancels the animation effect. `@keyframes` does not seem to be the right solution

```css
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10
}

nav a {
  font-family: DoubleBass;
  font-weight: normal;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.circle {
  background: #D73309;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 37.5vmin;
  height: 37.5vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -100px;
  right: -70px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1.2s, height 1.2s, box-shadow 1.2s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: width 1.2s, height 1.2s, box-shadow 1.2s;
}

.quotes {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 70px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.circle:hover {
  width: 60vmin;
  height: 60vmin;
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.circle:hover .quotes {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s;
  transition: opacity 1.2s;
}

.circleRe {
  background: #D73309;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 140vmax;
  height: 140vmax;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -500px;
  right: -400px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
    <a href="archive.html">Archive</a>
    <a href="films.html">Films</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="circle">
    <p class="quotes"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.links').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Show the UI Loader here
  $('.loaders').show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    //Hide the UI Loader after 5 seconds
    $('.loaders').hide();
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10
}

nav a {
  font-family: DoubleBass;
  font-weight: normal;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.circle {
  background: #D73309;
  width: 37.5vmin;
  height: 37.5vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: -100px;
  right: -70px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1.2s, height 1.2s, box-shadow 1.2s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: width 1.2s, height 1.2s, box-shadow 1.2s;
}

.quotes {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 70px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.loaders {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: .5;
  /* in FireFox */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  /* in IE */
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <a id='lnkHome' class='links' href="JavaScript:void(0);">Home</a>
    <a id='lnkResume' class='links' href="JavaScript:void(0);">Resume</a>
    <a id='lnkArchieve' class='links' href="JavaScript:void(0);">Archive</a>
    <a id='lnkFilms' class='links' href="JavaScript:void(0);">Films</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="circle">
    <p class="quotes">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="loaders" style="display:none;"></div>
</body>
```

Note:- Show loader on click and after some times, you can hide that loader.
so the user will not be able to interact with DOM(UI).

Hope this helps!